# Is (2R,3S)-2,3-dichloropentane optically inactive?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

Two confusing thing about (2⁠*R*,3⁠*S*)-2,3-dichloropentane:

1. The 2 stereocenters have opposite absolute configuration.
2. But there is no plane of symmetry.

So, is (2⁠*R*,3⁠*S*)-2,3-dichloropentane optically inactive?

(This is actually a follow-up question of:
[Monochlorination of 2-chloropentane and possible enantiomer products](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74261/monochlorination-of-2-chloropentane-and-possible-enantiomer-products?noredirect=1#comment130593_74261))

Comment: ad 1: the two stereo centers are different also constitutionally - structurally. So what should be the reason for optical inactivity?

Comment: You're misinterpreting the answers for the other question. Both of those compounds are chiral and count towards the 5 mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: @zhe Ok, now I understand. I had misinconception I had the notion that initial chirality of 2-carbon could change in the cholrination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have an optically inactive meso compound with two chiral centers:

1)  the chiral centers must have opposite configuration

2)  the chiral centers must have the same set of fragments bonded to them

Among other things the 2 carbon has a methyl group bonded to it versus the 3 carbon having an ethyl group instead.  You do not satisfy (2), so you do not have the symmetry required for a meso compound, and the molecule is still chiral and optically active.